# When is it that I have to stash local changes in git while switching branches?

Tags: git, git-branch

This is a follow up question to the question I posted earlier today, I am a git newbie and I am trying to under the functioning of git branches.

I am getting the

> Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches error .

Here is my git set up

> I create a file file1 in the branch Master, and  than I add and commit it.
>   I create a branch b1 and switch to that, Over there I make a few changes to file1 and commit it..
>   I switch back to master, where I make a few changes and I don't commit it..
>   Now when I try to switch to b1, I get the error shown above..

My question is that what are factors that are causing this error? What is it that git is seeing to throw this error.

---

Consider this scenario of a separate project

> I create a file temp in the branch Master, and  than I add and commit it.
>   I create a branch 'branch1', now branch1 has a copy of temp file.
>   I make a few changes in temp file in Master and don't commit it.

Now when I try to switch to branch1, why is it that it is not throwing that error? From my understanding both of the scenarios are similar. But it throws that error in the first scenario not the second one?

SO Can anyone explain to me, what are the parameters that govern the switching between windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I switch back to master, where I make a few changes and I don't commit it..
>   Now when I try to switch to b1, I get the error shown above

If you make changes to files which are present both in `master` and `b1`, you will get that message when changing back to `b1`.
Branch `b1` would overwrite the local modifications done in those file in `master`.

Your second scenario has modifications done to a private file (not versioned in git): changing branches won't affect its content, hence no need to stash.

---

You will see [many examples of git stash at codesearch](https://coderwall.com/p/search?scope=everything&search=stash):

- [Amiel Martin](https://coderwall.com/amiel) [points out that](https://coderwall.com/p/nfmrya):

> Do you ever find yourself doing this?

```
$ git checkout some_branch
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        Gemfile
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
Aborting
$ git stash
$ git checkout some_branch
$ git stash pop
```

> Here’s a nice little shortcut:

```
$ git checkout --merge some_branch
```

- [gitguys provides a good scenario for `git stash`](http://www.gitguys.com/topics/temporarily-stashing-your-work/).
- [This gist](https://github.com/mezis/git-whistles/blob/master/libexec/git-stash-and-checkout.sh) allows for a `stash-checkout-shash pop` in one command.

Comment: If you don't mind, can you please illustrate your point with an example?

Comment: @JoeDimaggio I have added a few links, but basically: if changing branch doesn't touch your current modification, you won't get a stash message. If changing a branch will touch the files you are currently modifying, you will be ask to stash. It is that simple.

Answer (score 2):

There are already several right answers, but here's another way to look at it.

Imagine you're shrunken way down and stuck inside a computer, and are given the job of "be the `git checkout` command".  A user does something like this:

```
$ cd somewhere
$ ls
... various commands, etc
$ echo something_extra >> some_file
$ git checkout branch
```

So now, you go see what it takes to `git checkout branch`.  First you find out whether the guy asking you to do stuff is in a git repo (he is) and what branch if any he's on now (let's say `master`, just for concreteness).  So it's possible to switch branches, which seems to be what he wants to do.

Next, you need to take a look at all the files involved in switching branches, including (maybe) `some_file`.

Is there a version of `some_file` in branch `branch`?  Is there a version of `some_file` in the current branch, `master`?  If there is, are those the same, or different?  What about the current working directory (and, since this is git, the "staging area", aka "index")?

Here are all your possibilities:

- The file is not in either branch.  It's untracked both ways, so, no problem!
- The file is in `master` but not in `branch`.  You're supposed to remove it.

  You need to check, now, whether it's "safe" to remove it.  It's "safe" if it's not staged for commit and the contents of the file match the contents in `master`.  (That means, you probably put it there earlier, when the guy did `git checkout master`.)  As a slightly oddball case, it's also "safe" if it's not there now: there's nothing to remove.
- The file is not in `master` but is in `branch`.  You're supposed to create it, with the contents as in `branch`.

  You need to check, now, whether it's "safe" to create it.  It's "safe" if it's not staged for commit and it's not there now either.  (In theory, it should also be safe if it's there now but already contains what you're supposed to put in it.  `git checkout` gives me an error here though—which is odd considering in the "oddball" cases, `git checkout` usually allows the switch.)
- The file is in both `master` *and* `branch`.  You're supposed to ... well, that depends!  Is it *the same* in both, or *different* in both?

This last case gets messy, especially with the difference between "index" and "working directory", but let's run through them:

- The file is in both branches, and is *the same* in both.  You are to do nothing, so it's OK to switch branches, even if the file is staged and/or modified.
- The file is in both branches, and is *different* in both.  You're supposed to replace its contents.  If it's not staged and not modified (`git status` shows nothing for the file), you're good to go.
- The file is in both branches, and is different in both, *and* the one in the work directory *doesn't* match the one in the current branch `master` *or* the one in the target branch `branch`.  If you replace it you'll lose the guy's changes, so you have to error-out.
- The oddball case here is: the file is staged and/or modified, but now matches the one in the target branch.  That is, someone made, to `master`, the same change that is already in `branch`.  In this case you don't have to overwrite the file, so you *may* be able to switch branches.  The staging area makes this harder, because when you do the checkout, you first have to write the new contents into the staging area, and only then copy it out to the work directory.  So you have to make sure it's the same (as the target-branch version) in the stage-area too, before allowing the `git checkout branch` to proceed.

In all cases, though, your job is: "make sure the guy won't lose changes he's put in the work directory or staging area".  If he *would* lose some changes, complain and quit.  Otherwise, allow the checkout, and update the staging area and the work tree.

(Because git's user interface is ... well, let's not say "deliberately hostile" :-) but rather "complicated due to history", the "switch branches" action of `git checkout` is only *one* of a number of different things you can have `git checkout` do.  In particular, `git checkout rev path` is actually a *different command*, that does not switch branches, and is perfectly happy to overwrite changes.  Just make sure you're only doing `git checkout branch` here, and not `git checkout branch and some file names`.  I'd be happier with this if all of the "overwrite" uses had a different action verb, but it is what it is.

I've also skipped over the "middle of a merge" cases.  If you have merge conflicts, the staging area is always modified and never matches, so you error-out here.  If no merge conflicts remain, `checkout` proceeds as usual, and if successful, aborts the merge.  I'm not sure I like the latter action—it seems safer to make the user `git merge --abort` manually—but any work "lost" in this case is merely choices made during the merge, as if that's "mere"....)

Answer (score 1):

You will get the error when the working directory changes that you have cannot be applied on top of the changes that are available to the files(s) in the other branch.

In the first scenario, master and branch have diverged. `file1` is changed in `b1`. It is not in master. But you make a local change on master's version, and switch branches. Now the changes cannot be applied as the version of `file1` in `b1` is different from what the base version was in master.

In scenario 2, the base copy of the file is same in both branches. Now local changes while any branch checked out will be same and you can easily switch between them.

Answer (score 0):

When switching branches, git will change the files in your working directory to match the files of the branch you are switching to.

However, what happens to uncommited changes? Exactly, they will get overwritten. And as they aren't committed, they will be lost forever.

To prevent that from happening, git emits a warning that tells you to commit or stash these uncomitted changes. There are several ways of getting rid of that warning:

- Switch the branch anyway (this will loose the uncomitted changes)
- Commit the changes
- Stash the changes

Switching the branch anyway is done by doing a `git reset --hard HEAD` before you switch the branch. That command will overwrite all the uncommitted changes.